# get selected categories or tags (using javascript) in GutenBerg?

Tags: block-editor

I was still unable to find out that in Gutenberg. Specifically, i used:

```
wp.data.select("core/editor").getPostEdits();
```

to find out how many categories were checked. But it missed already checked categories... So, which function should I use to access in sum, how many categories are select at this moment? where is that data stored?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the categories from inside the editor of a post you can make use of the following selectors:

The categories the post has in the published version:
`wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostAttribute("categories")`

The current categories of the edit (for example if the user has selected a new category but hasn't saved the post it will appear with this selector but not with the former):
`wp.data.select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("categories")`

This will give you an array with the `id` of each category.