# Getting the selected terms for custom taxonomies in the editor

Tags: custom-taxonomy, block-editor

After reading this answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324557/how-to-get-with-javascript-how-many-categories-or-tags-are-selected-in-gutenber/324560#324560), I can get the currently selected/checked terms for categories using this code:

```
wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostAttribute("categories")
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with custom taxonomies created with register_taxonomy(). Is there any other way to do this?

[This merge](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/2340/files/e713c0edcc2e83af58a0d7edc889de92513e5eea) seems like it might be relevant, but it's kind of hard for me to understand what's being implemented there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register a custom taxonomy make sure to set `show_in_rest` to `true`. This way the taxonomy will show in the REST API which is what Gutenberg uses to get the data.
Then you can use the selector:

`wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostAttribute("my_taxonomy");`

Comment: This answer is already accepted but do you know how to get the slugs/names of the terms? This call only returns the IDs of the selected terms.